# Selenium WebDriver Implicit wait

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver

How to make a implicitly wait like this in javascript webdriver?

python example:

`browser.implicitly_wait(1)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1);
```

Comment: Nope, I didn't find it in docs either, but I found it in webdriver.js source code. I also have been using this method a couple of times and it worked. Not sure about all webdriver versions though.

Comment: This is not working in my code. is there any change ??

driver.manage(...).timeouts is not a function

Comment: This answer does not apply to Javascript selenium-webdriver. @Jigs1212 here is Javascript implementation: `this.driver.manage().setTimeouts({ implicit: 20000, pageLoad: 10000 });`

Answer (score 3):

The correct function for the javascript API is

```
driver.sleep(1000)
```